# How to read the body of the email using aa?

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

How to read the body of an email from outlook using automation anywhere?

i am unable to read because my port number and host information is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is quite diffuse as you state already that your network settings are wrong, but instead of asking how to fix that you're asking how to handle expected data from the network. Please read our guide [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and focus on one issue in your question. You can click the `edit`-link below your question and change the text then. For the other issue it's better to ask a second question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to read email using **Get All Messages** command,  you have to set up mail settings, check the following link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040

Then, you can read the email body/messages within the loop using **$Email Message$** variable.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP is a push protocol and is used to send the mail.

**SMTP details for Outlook account:**

- Host: smtp-mail.outlook.com
- Port: 587

**SMTP details for Gmail account:**

- Host: smtp.gmail.com
- Port: 587

IMAP (internet message access protocol) are used to retrieve those mails at the receiver’s side.

**IMAP details for Outlook account:**

- Host: imap-mail.outlook.com
- Port: 993

**IMAP details for Gmail account:**

- Host: imap.gmail.com
- Port: 993

There are a lot of system variables available in automation anywhere related to email:

[image]

You can use the system variable - $Email Subject$ in Automation anywhere to read subject.

You can also refer [How to read Email using Automation Anywhere](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRCuNlGzius&list=PLkkGqdBS1r08Fd6meBZ7zHJXA15Q5Up2w&index=11)